# How to define in FireMonkey correct view to size of screen ?

Tags: android

I created Android application in RAD studio 10.1 and master View is good enough to smartphones displays (4-5.5 inch). Now I want to make view for tablets.
I used existing "Android 10" Tablet" view and corrected place of controls.
I checked it on tablet and it`s good. But when I run my application on 4" phone I see that in IDE it have old correct places of control but on phone it`s moved like on tablet view ! It`s mean that FireMonkey selected not correct views to screen size.
How to define correct view to size of screen ?